# In Macos, how to Move pasteboard `promiseKeeper` Function to a Specific Child Thread to Avoid Main Thread Blocking?

Tags: macos, qt, paste, nspasteboard, cfrunloop

**Questions:**
I am currently using the QT 15.15.2

1. I am currently using the `<ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>` library. Based on my understanding:

   - I can use `PasteboardSetPromiseKeeper` to set a promise keeper function for clipboard handling (which I believe is a callback function for rendering clipboard data).
   - I can use `PasteboardPutItemFlavor` to place empty data.
   - When the user presses Ctrl+V, it should trigger the `PromiseKeeper` event.
2. However, I am currently facing an issue where the `PromiseKeeper` function is running on my main thread, causing my UI to freeze and certain control flows to hang.
3. I have already created a subthread using `QThread`, and both `PasteboardCreate` and `PasteboardSetPromiseKeeper` are running within the subthread.

**Partial pseudocode**

```
// in child thread context
OSStatus err = PasteboardCreate(kPasteboardClipboard, &m_pasteboard);
err = PasteboardSetPromiseKeeper(m_pasteboard, promiseKeeper, this);

OSStatus MacClipboard::promiseKeeper(PasteboardRef pasteboard, PasteboardItemID pasteboardItemID, CFStringRef uti, void *_macClipboard)
{
    qDebug() << "promiseKeeper Thread id=" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    
    // In this case, I need to access the data on the network in another thread.

    macClipboard->_promisMutex.lock();
    macClipboard->_createPromise(pasteboardItemID, formatName);
    bool timeouted = !(macClipboard->_promisWaitCondition.wait(&macClipboard->_promisMutex, 5000));
    macClipboard->_promisMutex.unlock();

    const CFDataRef cfData = CFDataCreate(nullptr, (UInt8*)macClipboard->promiseData()->constData(), macClipboard->promiseData()->size());
    resultStatus = PasteboardPutItemFlavor(pasteboard, pasteboardItemID, uti, cfData, kPasteboardFlavorNoFlags);

    return noErr;
}
```

1. I have already tried nesting multiple layers of threads, but it had no effect. The `promiseKeeper` function still runs on the main thread.
2. I suspect it may be related to the event loop of the macOS system. After referring to the QT source code, it seems that I need to create a "run loop context" in the context of the subthread. However, I'm not very clear on its usage, so I haven't tried it yet.

Did I misunderstand? I don't need to block promiseKeeper? Then how can I achieve the goal of retrieving data from the network and placing it into the clipboard when the user presses CTRL+V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very rare for Apple APIs to offer you a choice of which thread to get called on. In most cases, you either always get called on the main thread, or (particularly for asynchronous APIs with a completion callback) you might get called back on whatever thread you started from.

And sometimes (as with Pasteboard Manager) this isn't documented and you are not really guaranteed any particular choice of thread—the Pasteboard Manager does not guarantee it will call you on the main thread, so don't rely on that, but neither does it guarantee that it *won't* call you on the main thread, so don't rely on that, either.

Basically, you have to assume that this callback will block the main thread. Moreover, there is no way to get Pasteboard Manager to call you on a different thread, nor is there any way to say “call me back later”, nor “I've started getting that ready and will let you know when it is”.

(Part of this is an artifact of how pasting works in the *receiving* application: the receiving application simply tells the pasteboard API—whichever one it's using; there are two, down from three in the 32-bit era—to give it whatever's on the pasteboard. That's a synchronous API; it assumes the data is already available, and if it isn't, blocks until it is, even if that means going through a promise keeper, pasteboard filter, or both. So yeah, it's normal for pasting to hang in these sorts of situations—just ask anyone who's copied something from their iPad and pasted it on their Mac.)

---

Pasteboard promises, particularly to modern eyes, might look like they solve two different needs:

- the need to promise something that would be expensive/slow to create or retrieve, in the hope that the promise might never get called in
- the need to asynchronously begin producing or procuring data *when* a promise is called in, and deliver the data when it is ready

But that's not correct. Pasteboard promises are really designed for the former only. You offer a promise in the hope that it won't get called, but if it is called, you're expected to service the request synchronously—blocking the whole time.

(The normal use case is providing files, particularly for drag-and-drop; that isn't free, but, especially on a modern system, it's not nearly as slow as a network access. Pasting things from the network is not unheard of—see the above reference to Universal Clipboard—but it is relatively unusual and certainly not what this API is designed for.)

What I would recommend is to make the promise, then start your threaded download *eagerly* (that is, right when you make the promise), in the hope that if and when your promise keeper gets called, the download will have finished, or at least be closer to the finish line.

This implies, of course, that you'll need some way to expire and release/delete the downloaded data if the promise never gets called. What that looks like will depend on where you're downloading it to (memory vs. storage), how big it is, how time-sensitive it is, etc. Those are questions you'll need to answer for yourself.

It also suggests that you might want to consider a caching system so that things only need to be downloaded once unless expired.

You might even consider building an asset library UI of some sort that makes explicit the division between “things that need to be downloaded” and “things that can be pasted”: a user would go to your asset library and download something, and *then* be able to copy and paste it. I generally prefer to hide these sorts of implementation artifacts, but in this case, it's better than hanging.

---

**TL;DR:** Start the download when you create the promise. If and when your promise gets called, hopefully you're either ready to deliver on it or at least won't have to block as long. Blocking is, unfortunately, expected in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Peter Hosey. On Windows, clipboard communication is done using window messages. The clipboard rendering function blocks the thread of the specified window until it receives the clipboard data and returns. However, on Linux with X11, it operates as an asynchronous event notification operation. Copying, pasting, and data rendering in the clipboard are all done through event notifications, and it doesn't block any thread.  Now on macos platform, It seems that I will need to start another process specifically to handle macOS pasteboard events without affecting my main UI process.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that I am currently exploring the clipboard redirection feature in `Microsoft Remote Desktop` ( RDP connection software on macos). It has already implemented the functionality I desire, but I am unsure about the underlying principles of its implementation. I am continuing my research and learning process.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting concept. So, when you get your Copy command, start another process and then have *that* process make the promise and start the download? Seems like it could work. Note that it should still start the download eagerly, to minimize the amount of time the *pasting* application has to wait (hung the whole time) for the promise to be fulfilled.